# How to display all the history suggestions of the input element of the form in Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, autocomplete, autofill

the maximum number of suggestions in chrome is 6, Firefox can scroll to display all the history, how to add css to make chrome behave like Firefox?[image: chrome&Firefox input suggentions]